# Loop calculations on different sized dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am trying to create a dataframe from three dataframes. One dataframe is 9900x140 whereas the other two are 9900x70. I have a calculation I want to apply to the data to create a new dataframe (9900x140) that takes the element value and multiplies it by a set of values. The first column of df 2 and 3 applies to the first and second column of df1, column 2 of df2 and df3 apply to the third and fourth column of df2 and df3 and so forth. I know that the  `apply` family of functions are better to use in R but I was unable to figure out how to do this using that family of functions, so I tried making a for loop for it. Here is an example of what I am trying to do with smaller dataframes

```
#initialize example data
pracdf1=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*140),ncol=140,nrow=100))
pracdf2=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*70),ncol=70,nrow=100))
pracdf3=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*70),ncol=70,nrow=100))
pracmultipliers=c(15,10,-.5,-.9)

#initialize new df for calculations
calcdf=data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(pracdf1),ncol=ncol(pracdf1)))

#perform calculations
k=1
for(i in 1:nrow(pracdf2)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(pracdf2)){
    calcdf[i,k]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracdf1[i,k]*pracmultipliers[2]+
      pracdf2[i,j]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracdf3[i,j]*pracmultipliers[4]
    k=k+1
    calcdf[i,k]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracdf1[i,k]*pracmultipliers[2]+
      pracdf2[i,j]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracdf3[i,j]*pracmultipliers[4]
    k=k+1
  }
}
```

When I run this code, however, I get an error

```
Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero
```

I understand that this means that the input is NULL or has a zero length, but I'm not sure how that applies to my code here, as I can't figure out how this results in a zero length vector. If anyone could explain this problem, and/or offer a better solution for this issue, it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Here is a smaller example, the steps I would have done without putting the data in the for loop I had planned, and the expected output

```
#initialize dataframes
pracconcdata=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(3*4),ncol=4,nrow=3))
pracrhdata=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(3*2),ncol=2,nrow=3))
pracTdata=as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(3*2),ncol=2,nrow=3))
pracmultipliers=c(15,10,-.5,-.9)

calcdata=data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(pracconcdata),ncol=ncol(pracconcdata)))

#calculate new data (long form)

calcdata[1,1]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[1,1]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[1,1]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[1,1]*pracmultipliers[4]

calcdata[1,2]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[1,2]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[1,1]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[1,1]*pracmultipliers[4]

calcdata[1,3]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[1,3]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[1,2]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[1,2]*pracmultipliers[4]

calcdata[1,4]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[1,4]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[1,2]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[1,2]*pracmultipliers[4]

calcdata[2,1]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[2,1]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[2,1]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[2,1]*pracmultipliers[4]

calcdata[2,2]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[2,2]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[2,1]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[2,1]*pracmultipliers[4]

calcdata[2,3]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[2,3]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[2,2]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[2,2]*pracmultipliers[4]

calcdata[2,4]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[2,4]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[2,2]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[2,2]*pracmultipliers[4]

calcdata[3,1]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[3,1]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[3,1]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[3,1]*pracmultipliers[4]

calcdata[3,2]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[3,2]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[3,1]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[3,1]*pracmultipliers[4]

calcdata[3,3]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[3,3]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[3,2]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[3,2]*pracmultipliers[4]

calcdata[3,4]=pracmultipliers[1]+pracconcdata[3,4]*pracmultipliers[2]+
  pracrhdata[3,2]*pracmultipliers[3]+pracTdata[3,2]*pracmultipliers[4]


#expected output

dput(calcdata)
structure(list(X1 = c(12.3210747915468, 25.1484566241992, 6.71748751528764
), X2 = c(4.12393989109251, 0.254435260806873, 2.52020178121514
), X3 = c(21.8023268323184, 9.2565900612999, 18.9277557430817
), X4 = c(1.61401361689925, 13.881360671084, 19.0283660368017
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why are you looping through the rows?

Comment: Part of the problem is the `k = k + 1`. For each row for each column, you are going to keep incrementing k. That means you end up with 14,001 as the final value of k. That does not work with only 140 columns in `calcdf`. It might help if you had a smaller example with expected output.

Comment: Can you create an example with smaller dataframes and show expected output for it?

Comment: I have added an example above that uses a 3x6 df and also did what I was hoping to do manually for that size df